# 複数の辞書に対してループで特定の処理を実行したい

Tags: python, python3, csv

不特定数の辞書をcsvに記載したいのですが、私の知識では方法をみつけることが出来ませんでした。
もし、何か方法ございましたらご教示頂けないでしょうか。

[試したコード]
以下コードは辞書が2つあった場合にやりたいことを実現出来たコードとなります。
ただ、実際は辞書(d1,d2...)はユーザー入力のため、不特定で対応できるコートが必要となります。

```python
import csv

labels = ['FData_1', 'FData_2', 'FData_3']
d1 = {'FData_1': 'test', 'FData_2': 2, 'FData_3': 3}
d2 = {'FData_1': 10, 'FData_3': 30}

with open('sample_dictwriter.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=labels)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(d1)
    writer.writerow(d2)
```

#writer.writerow(dn)をfor文などで回す方法を探しております。

どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 何処に有るデータから、どのように辞書が作られて、どんな変数にどんな形で格納されるのか？ といった情報を整理して追記してみてください。その過程で自分で気付くこともあるのでは？

Comment: 助言頂きありがとうございます！ 頂いた助言をもとに、辞書を複数作るのではなく、1つの辞書を使い回しすればやりたいことが実現できることが分かりました。本当にありがとうございました